# Can I replace SQL*Loader code with Java to read ctl file for uploading heavy file without imacting performance?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm currently using SQL*Loader to load heavy file(around 60k records) in oracle database. I want to know if it's possible to I can read ctl file from java instead of SQL*Loader. I know that's what purpose of SQL*Loader but still if by any chance.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of reading the lines of the file is in memory – both Guava and Apache Commons IO provide a quick way to do just that:

```
Files.readLines(new File(path), Charsets.UTF_8);
FileUtils.readLines(new File(path));
```

The problem with this approach is that all the file lines are kept in memory – which will quickly lead to OutOfMemoryError if the File is large enough.

The same can be achieved using the Commons IO library without memory impact, by using the custom LineIterator provided by the library:

```
LineIterator it = FileUtils.lineIterator(theFile, "UTF-8");
try {
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        String line = it.nextLine();
        // do something with line
    }
} finally {
    LineIterator.closeQuietly(it);
}
```

Comment: Yeah that would be quite slow as well. What if I use spring Batch process? Would it still be time consuming?

Comment: How long does it take right now? Spring Batch can help, because it allows you to set how much items are kept in memory before writing it to the db, but in the end it's just a tool and performance depends mostly on the file size.

Comment: with SQL*Loader for 60k records in file takes around 15-20 mins.

Comment: Correcting title now